# Unable to select user property inside remote config in firebase, it is greyed out

Tags: android, firebase-console, firebase-remote-config

[image]

Unable to select user property inside remote config in firebase, it is greyed out

Comment: User properties can either be logged explicitly by your application code, or automatically when you use Analytics. If you aren't using Analytics or logging them explicitly, I'd expect that to be the reason the UI stays disabled.

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Same here, I'm. using analytics in my app and logging custom user parameters bu the user property is still disabled. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: +1 facing same issue, I've been checking it daily from last 5 days, but it doesn't reflect user properties from analytics.

Answer (score 7):

You must first add the user property to Firebase -> **Custom definitions**.

1. Go to Firebase -> Custom definitions
2. Click **Create custom dimensions**
3. Select Scope to be **User**
4. Complete the remaining fields (note you can't add user_id)
5. This step might be optional but had to wait a few hours for it to appear.

[image: list of new custom dimensions]

Currently Firebase doesn't seem to allow for the built-in/automatic user properties to be allowed here. `user_id` would be a really good example of something you might want but can't have.

[image: image showing test property in remote config]